# How can I style Listing captions the same as Figure captions?

Tags: listings, captions, lstlisting

Here is my listing caption format:

[image]

Here is my figure caption format:

[image]

How can I format the listing captions to be the same as figure captions? here is the relevant bit from the style file:

```
% Revised formatting for figure captions and table titles. 
\newsavebox\newcaptionbox\newdimen\newcaptionboxwid

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{
 \vskip 10pt 
        \baselineskip 11pt
        \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1. #2}
        \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        \sbox{\newcaptionbox}{\small\sl #1.~}
        \newcaptionboxwid=\wd\newcaptionbox
        \usebox\newcaptionbox {\footnotesize #2}
        \else 
          \centerline{{\small\sl #1.} {\small #2}} 
        \fi}

\def\fnum@figure{Figure \thefigure}
\def\fnum@table{Table \thetable}
% \def\fnum@lstlisting{Listing \thelstlisting}  %% this didn't work
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: It matters which listing package you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package [`caption`](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) and match the formatting in the main style file `my_base_style.sty`:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{justification=justified, labelfont=it, font= 
{footnotesize}, labelsep=period, skip=10pt}
```

Be sure to do this *after* `\usepackage{my_base_style}`.